# Format date in search query webpart - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

what i need to do is to compare two dates without year e.g if i have 06/12/2003 < 07/04/2012, i want this 06/12 < 07/04 how can i do that into a query builder?

[image]

if somebody can help me i'll apreciate so much.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the query builder. What you can do is to create a calculated column with a formula like `=TEXT([yourdatecolumn],"mm/dd")` and map it to a Refinable field and use that for comparison

Comment: thanks for the replay, the problem is that this date doesn´t come from a custom list but from sharepoint user profile, what can i do?

Comment: IMO, neither content search nor search results is the way to go, you will need to use JSOM and REST to query the user profile and get the date fields and compare them using native JavaScript or Moment.JS to do that. Refer to this article for using User Profile REST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx